# Is there a connection between users named "user#######" and unregistered users?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, user-accounts, display-names, unregistered-users

Why are some user name formatted user########, is this linked with unregistered users and if does a unregistered status appear on every unregistered users profile?

Comment: I removed all of the comments here because they were really tedious and got in the way of the answer, which I believe answers both the long and short forms of this question and thus should be an end to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user1231231` usernames are generated by the system if you don't choose your own display name when you sign up. It is unrelated with being registered or not.

You can see whether a user is registered or not in their profile. Unregistered users have "**unregistered**" right beside their name.

Here's an example from Unix & Linux:

[image]

That's an unregistered user that chose a username. You can find plenty of registered users on Stack Overflow that didn't change their display name from the default `user314159`.

Comment: Thanks Mat, I know it's a bit of a basic question, I am strange, and like to understand the small things, as much as the big things

Comment: Worth to mention the [users list](http://stackoverflow.com/users) as well as the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) show only registered users; only the dev team and diamond moderators can search in the full list.