# What's up with the all the users whose names start with "user"?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, display-names

Why are there so many user names like `user123456`?

Is that really their name, or just the name that I'm allowed to see?

I don't believe that so many people chose such a uniform name because they wanted to have a generic name.

Previously I assumed that these were users who deleted their profiles or perhaps died or were imported from another site, but there are certainly a lot of examples of users with great activity and recent activity.

So, where do they come from?

Comment: Just the default... and some small percentage of users who are odd and opt to leave the default.

Comment: Related: [Is there a connection between users named “user#######” and unregistered users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186116/300411)

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes, thank you, and I think my question is essentially a duplicate.  Funny, I couldn't find the other question, and it wasn't suggested while I wrote this one (I use that suggested question thing to do my actual search half the time).